# setting local ruby version with rbenv not working?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I cant really understand the problem here:

```
   ➜  myflixx git:(master) ✗ rbenv local
2.1.1
➜  myflixx git:(master) ✗ rails -v
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1
➜  myflixx git:(master) ✗ rake -T
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1
```

Why is it complaining about Ruby version 2.0.0 when I've already set the local version (with rbenv) to 2.1.1?

Is it something that I'm missing? thanks for your time!

Comment: What's the output of `rbenv versions`? And `cat .ruby-version`?

Comment: system
* 2.1.1 (set by /Users/Fernando_L/documents/ruby/rnr/myflixx/.ruby-version) and for the cat: ➜  myflixx git:(master) ✗ cat .ruby-version
2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

This makes sure your paths are correctly set.

In Bashrc or equivalent:

`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"`

`eval "$(rbenv init -)"`

Install everything and locally define what ruby version to use for the app.

`brew install rbenv ruby-build`

`rbenv install <ruby-version>`

`rbenv rehash`

`rbenv local <ruby-version>`

Restart terminal or source the bashrc.